# LINQ Query returning IQueryable, need it to be a single result

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I currently have a LINQ query written in one my controllers that I want to return a single blog post (based off a model) with corresponding comments and topics.

This is what I currently have as my query which I used to return a list of all my blog posts for the home page.  I added "where p.id == id (which is the parameter taken in by the ActionResult to fetch the correct post.

```
var post = from p in db.Set<BlogPost>()
                   where p.id == id
                   select new PostViewModel
                              {
                                  Id = p.id,
                                  Title = p.Title,
                                  DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
                                  Content = p.Content,
                                  Topics = p.Topics,
                                  Comments = p.Comments,
                                  CommentCount = p.Comments.Count
                              };

return View(post);
```

The return currently is sending an IQueryable when I just want it to be a single post.  Currently I have a foreach in my razor view which is useless and wrong but it works.  How can I change this to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
return View(post.SingleOrDefault());
```

Or if you want to have an exception in the case list is empty:

```
return View(post.Single());
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if more than one element is in the list too.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman, Yes, exactly as needed by the question: "I want to return a single blog post", Also if you see OPs query: `where p.id == id`, So having more than one post for same ID is wrong.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman, Oh I didn't read your last comment carefully :)

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Thank you!  As you can see I am quite new to this... Looks like I need to learn some LINQ basics :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `First()` or `Single()` (which one is right for you depends on context) to your query:

```
return View(post.First());
```

Comment: That's twice you've beaten me to a LINQ question, damn you :P. Hehe. I'll upvote you tomorrow, I've maxed my daily allowance of votes today :/

Answer (score 1):

Just do `post.First()` that should do the trick. Really any function that produces a concrete value will work. [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx), [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx), [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx), [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx), [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx), or [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx)

I have included the links to each method so you can see what works for you. It sounds like you will want a First or Single variation, depending on if you want errors if more than one post is pulled

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you want to use First or Single:

```
return View(post.Single());
```

The difference between them is that `Single` will throw an exception if more than one matching row is found.

Answer (score 0):

replace your LINQ with this

```
var post = (from p in db.Set<BlogPost>()
               where p.id == id
               select new PostViewModel
                          {
                              Id = p.id,
                              Title = p.Title,
                              DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
                              Content = p.Content,
                              Topics = p.Topics,
                              Comments = p.Comments,
                              CommentCount = p.Comments.Count
                          }).FirstOrDefault();
```